# FFmpeg concat problem

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I just want to add black video at the beginning of the video

I have found following commands.

```
ffmpeg -i s1.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=black -t 10 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=1*iw/1/sar:ih/1[wm][base];[base][wm]concat=2" output.mp4
```

**MainQuestion:**
[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concat requires videos to have the same sample aspect ratio as well as the same resolution.

So, in this case,

```
ffmpeg -i s1.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=black -t 10 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[wm][base];[wm]setsar=1[wm];[base][wm]concat=2" output.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i s1.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=black -t 10 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[wm][base];[base][wm]concat=2:unsafe=1" output.mp4
```

Comment: I carried out above command, and the terminal was stuck。 @Gyan

Comment: Run command with -report added and share report. Kill ffmpeg after a minute if it doesn't exit.

Comment: I found a error:
[Parsed_concat_1 @ 0x7f9d74e086c0] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 212x160, SAR 160:159) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (212x160, SAR 1:1)

Comment: Use the 2nd command.